# spring data json populator failed

Tags: json, spring-data

I have a *test.json* file as bellow

```
[{"_class":"com.abc.Xyz",  
  "uid":1,  
  "name":"first"  
 }, {  
  "uid":2,  
  "name":"second"  
}]
```

under resources directory and a *config class* as below

```
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean repositoryPopulator() {

        Resource sourceData = new ClassPathResource("test.json");

        Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();

        factory.setResources(new Resource[] { sourceData });
        return factory;
    }
}
```

When the code runs, I meet the exception as below

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:214) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.init.Jackson2ResourceReader.readSingle(Jackson2ResourceReader.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.init.Jackson2ResourceReader.readFrom(Jackson2ResourceReader.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.init.ResourceReaderRepositoryPopulator.readObjectFrom(ResourceReaderRepositoryPopulator.java:146) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Any hint?

Comment: my ide generated a blank item at the end of the json file. deleting it resolves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, my ide generated a blank field at the end of the json file. after delete it, everything goes fine